# Not able to append List to List Python ( N-Queen Problem )

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner in Leetcode & Python and I tried to solve the N-Queen Problem. Below is the solution in Python which passed submission

```
class Solution:
        def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
            def isSafe(row, x_col):
                # check row
                for x in range(n):
                    if placed[row][x] is True and x != x_col:
                        return False
                # check column
                for x in range(n):
                    if placed[x][x_col] is True and x != row:
                        return False
    
                # check diagnol
                i, j = row, x_col
                while i > 0 and j < n - 1:
                    if placed[i - 1][j + 1] is True:
                        return False
                    i -= 1
                    j += 1
    
                i, j = row, x_col
    
                while i < n - 1 and j < 0:
                    if placed[i + 1][j - 1] is True:
                        return False
                    i -= 1
                    j += 1
    
                # #check offdiagnol
                i, j = row, x_col
                while i > 0 and j > 0:
                    if placed[i - 1][j - 1] is True:
                        return False
                    i -= 1
                    j -= 1
    
                i, j = row, x_col
    
                while i < n-1 and j < n-1:
                    if placed[i][j] is True:
                        return False
                    i += 1
                    j += 1
                return True
    
            def process(currconfig, matrix, n, row):
                    #base condition
                    if row == n:
                        curr = []
                        for x in range(n):
                            curr.append(currconfig[x])
                        totalconfig.append(currconfig)
                        return
    
                    for x_col in range(n):
                        if isSafe(row, x_col):
                            path = x_col * '.' + 'Q' + (n - x_col - 1) * '.'
                            currconfig.append(path)
                            matrix[row][x_col] = True
                            #process recursively called
                            process(currconfig, matrix, n, row + 1)
                            currconfig.pop()
                            matrix[row][x_col] = False
    
            configuration = []
            totalconfig = []
            placed = [[False for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
            process(configuration, placed, n, 0)
            return totalconfig

a = Solution()
print(a.solveNQueens(4))
```

I only have a doubt about the base condition of the process function. In the process function's base condition I initially did this and got empty Lists appended to totalconfig no matter what, CASE I:

```
def process(currconfig, matrix, n, row):
                    if row == n:
                        totalconfig.append(currconfig)
                        return
```

so spent a few hours trying to get around the problem and weirdly enough for me this worked, CASE II :

```
def process(currconfig, matrix, n, row):
                        if row == n:
                            curr = []
                            for x in range(n):
                                curr.append(currconfig[x])
                            totalconfig.append(currconfig)
                            return
```

I don't get why the CASE I did not work but CASE II worked. What am I missing...How is "currconfig" in CASE I different from "curr" in CASE II

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you are not using functions (methods) in classes correctly.

Basically, the first argument is the `self` which refers to itself. In your case, `currconfig` is `self`.

So presumably the function should have looked like this:

```py
def process(self, currconfig, matrix, n, row):    # <---added self
                    if row == n:
                        totalconfig.append(currconfig)
                        return
```

Comment: I do not think that is what is going wrong, since i'm able to print currconfig correctly, it's just it won't append to totalconfig

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108130/getting-empty-list-even-though-appending-while-using-recursion 

this was able to solve my query

Comment: @Aryan,  i was going to suggest this initially, because it is a classic problem. However, the function is in a `class`, so referencing correctly (ie. with `self`) would have avoided this in the first instance !!  so you have fallen foul of another classic problem :)  `self`.

Comment: This is wrong. It's just a regular function (as it's written nested *inside the method*, not directly in the class), not some object's method.